# Reading a single element from HDF5 file

Tags: c#, hdf5

Could you please provide me with an example of reading a single element from HDF5 file using HDF5DotNet library. I know how to read the full array into the memory and select the necessary element by index. The problem that I don't want to read the full array and would like to use the H5S.selectElements method (http://hdf5.net/api/M_HDF5DotNet_H5S_selectElements_4_9e6f2387.aspx).
So far I've created the following:

```
H5.Open();
H5FileId fileId = H5F.open(this.filePath, H5F.OpenMode.ACC_RDONLY);
var dSet = H5D.open(fileId, "/Link");
var dSpace = H5D.getSpace(dSet);
var dDims = H5S.getSimpleExtentDims(dSpace);
var dType = H5D.getType(dSet);

H5S.selectElements(dSpace, H5S.SelectOperator.SET, InpPtr numElements,long [] coord);
```

I can not figure out how to define the numElements parameter and coord of the element (I have 3 dimensional array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [HDF5 support doc](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/H5S/H5Sselect_elements.htm)

Assuming your DataSet is As Follows: (2D for simplicity explaining how the parameters work)

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

And you wanted to select the **6** and only the **6**.
That means that you want one element located in the second row and the third column. (One Indexed).

That means that you will need a 1 by 2 array of points in the selection array. (Zero Indexed).

```
1 2
```

If you wanted to select the 7 also, then the selection array would look like this. (Zero Indexed).

```
1 2 2 0
```

The related calls would be:

```
H5S.selectElements(dSpace, H5S.SelectOperator.SET, 1, new long [] { 1, 2 });
H5S.selectElements(dSpace, H5S.SelectOperator.SET, 2, new long [] { 1, 2, 2, 0 });
```

---

Translating to a 3D dataspace, we just add an extra value to the selection array.

That is:

```
1 2 0
```

Will select the point (2,3,1)

If you wanted to select a second value, then the selection array would look like this. (Zero Indexed).

```
1 2 0 1 2 1
```

Will select the points (2,3,1), (2,3,2).

The related calls would be:

```
H5S.selectElements(dSpace, H5S.SelectOperator.SET, 1, new long [] { 1, 2, 0 });
H5S.selectElements(dSpace, H5S.SelectOperator.SET, 2, new long [] { 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1 });
```

**Note**: That I have never used HDF5, describing call based on documentation, so there may be errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: My Pleasure. Also, you may want to note pros/cons with the method you used.

Answer (score 1):

Using [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) in C#, reading one particular element of a three dimensional dataset can be done as follows (assume that the dataset is called `my_dataset` and the element to read is at position 2, 3 and 5 in the first, second and third dimension respectively):

```
HDFql.Execute("SELECT FROM my_dataset[2, 3, 5]");
```

From there, you can retrieve the element by doing the following (assume that `my_dataset` is of datatype integer):

```
HDFql.CursorFirst();
System.Console.WriteLine("Element is " + HDFql.CursorGetInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found another approach to solve the problem - using H5S.selectHyperslab method. Maybe it's not so elegant but it seems to work fine.

```
H5.Open();
H5FileId fileId = H5F.open(this.filePath, H5F.OpenMode.ACC_RDONLY);
var dSet = H5D.open(fileId, "/Link");
var dSpace = H5D.getSpace(dSet);
var dDims = H5S.getSimpleExtentDims(dSpace);
var dType = H5D.getType(dSet);
//E.g. to extract the value with coordinates [0,1,0]:
H5DataSpaceId memspaceid = H5S.create_simple(1, new long[] { 1, 1, 1 });
H5S.selectHyperslab(memspaceid, H5S.SelectOperator.SET, new long[] { 0, 1, 0 }, new long[] { 1, 1, 1 });
H5S.selectHyperslab(dSpace, H5S.SelectOperator.SET, new long[] { 0, 1, 0 }, new long[] { 1, 1, 1 });

//array to read data
double[] readDataBank = new double[1];
H5DataTypeId typeId = new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_DOUBLE);
H5D.read(dSet, dType, memspaceid, dSpace,new H5PropertyListId(new H5P.Template()), new H5Array<double>(readDataBank));
```